# Formulário de pesquisa de satisfação

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma seguinte duvida, pois montei um formulário de pesquisa e infelizmente ele não ta inserido no banco de dados, eu possivelmente estou deixando passar alguma coisa.

código de PHP de cadastro -->

```
<?php
include_once 'conexao.php';
if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST['cadastrar'] == 'sim');
  $novos_campos = array();
  $campos_post = $_POST['campos'];

  $respostas = array();
  foreach($campos_post as $indice => $valor){
    $novos_campos[$valor['name']] = $valor['value'];

  }if(!strstr($novos_campos['cpf']) <> 11){
     $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
     $respostas['getErro'] = 'Insira corretamente o cpf...';

   }elseif(!strlen($novos_campos['telefone']) <> 11){
     $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
     $respostas['getErro'] = 'Insira seu telefone corretamente...';

   }elseif(!strstr($novos_campos['email'], '@')){
     $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
     $respostas['getErro'] = 'E-mail invalido...';

   }else{
     $respostas['erro'] = 'nao';
     $inserir_banco = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pesquisa_satisfacao SET nome = ?, cpf = ?, telefone = ?, email = ?, nota = ?, nota_comentario = ?, relacao_hospital = ?, servicos = ?, alaviacao_1 = ?, avaliacao_2 = ?, avaliacao_3 = ?, final_comunicar = ?, sugestao = ?");

     $array_sql = array(
       $novos_campos['nome'],
       $novos_campos['cpf'],
       $novos_campos['telefone'],
       $novos_campos['email'],
       $novos_campos['nota'],
       $novos_campos['nota_comentario'],
       $novos_campos['relacao_hospital'],
       $novos_campos['servicos'],
       $novos_campos['avaliacao_1'],
       $novos_campos['avaliacao_2'],
       $novos_campos['avaliacao_3'],
       $novos_campos['final_comunicar'],
       $novos_campos['sugestao'];

     );
     if(inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){
       $respostas['msg'] = 'inserido corretamente...';
     }else{
       $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
       $respostas['getErro'] = 'Por favor, tente mais tarde...';
     }
   }
   echo json_encode($respostas);


endif;
}?>
```

Desta maneira que eu estou fazendo, mas na hora da inserção para banco, ele não insere.

Comment: Repare que no if que verifica se foi executado está com erro de sintaxe.

Altere essa linha:
`if(inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){`
Para essa:
`if($inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){`

Comment: entao, eu ja tinha corrigido, e ainda persiste o erro

Comment: Seu array `$array_sql` possui um erro, no ultimo item, você esta usando ponto e virgula... `$novos_campos['sugestao'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o INSERT possui um erro:

```
INSERT INTO pesquisa_satisfacao SET nome = ?, cpf = ?, telefone = ?, email = ?, 
nota = ?, nota_comentario = ?, relacao_hospital = ?, servicos = ?,
```

> **alaviacao_1 = ?**

, 
    avaliacao_2 = ?, avaliacao_3 = ?, final_comunicar = ?, sugestao = ?

Comment: entao o codigo ja ajeitei todos os erros de escrita, só q ainda sim persirte e nnao ser inserido

Answer (score 0):

se você já corrigiu todos os erros provavelmente o problema está na sua tabela já verificou se o id da tabela foi adicionado um AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: ja sim verifiquei e o id é auto increment